# Jenkins передача переменной из вызываемой джобы

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

У меня есть 2 пайплайна - **"А"** и **"В"**.
Пайплайн **"А"** вызывает пайплайн **"В"** (с помощью "build job").
В пайплайне **"В"** создается переменная *"table"* и ей придается значение.
Как мне переменную *"table"* передать из **"В"** в пайплайн **"А"** и использовать в дальнейшем в пайплайне **"А"**?.

Answer (score 0):

Решил задачу так:

1. Пайплайн "А" вызывает пайплайн "В"
2. Пайплайн "В" создает переменные, значения которых мне нужно использовать в пайплайне "А". Создаю JSON-файл в пайплайне "В" и в него записываю значения нужных мне переменных.
3. После завершения работы пайплайна "В", в пайплайне "А" считываю этот файл и достаю оттуда значения переменных.

Может кому пригодится:)